# Validity of arguments in discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I am having trouble with this problem.
find out whether the following argument is valid:

---

> All girls are tall.
>
> Anyone who is tall and dark will pass.
>
> Claire is a girl.
>
> Conclusion: Claire will pass.

---

converting the statements to predicate logic:

---

- $G(x)=x$ is a girl
- $A(x)=x$ is tall
- $B(X)=x$ is dark
- $C(x)=x$ passes

$\quad{∀(x)[G(x)\to A(x)]
\\∀(x)[[A(x)\land B(x)]\to C(x)]
\\ G(c)\to A(c)}$
.....................c stands for claire

Am i right till now? and please help me proceed to finish the problem .

Comment: if that it what you mean so the statement isnot Tautological true, as if B(c) $\iff$ F

Comment: What is F? in B(c)<=>F

Comment: it would be easier to work with had you used G,T,D,P for is girl, tall, dark, passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Premise 3 should just be $G(c)$, Claire is a girl.

Then from premise 1 and the rule of Universal Elimination you have $G(c)\to A(c)$ as statement four.

Premise 3, statement 4, and *modus ponens* will then give $A(c)$ as statement 5.

$$\begin{array}{r|l:l}1 & \forall x~(G(x)\to A(x)& \text{Premise }1\\ 2 & \forall x~((A(x)\wedge B(x))\to C(x)) & \text{Premise }2\\ 3& G(c) & \text{Premise }3\\ 4 & G(c)\to A(c) & 1, \forall\textsf{E}\\ 5 & A(c) & 3,4,{\to}\mathsf E\end{array}$$

However, your mission is to prove $C(c)$, Claire will pass.  Can you get to there from here?

> No.

Comment: So  the argument is invalid?

Comment: In conclusion, Clair will pass if she is dark.  Is that fair?

Comment: Yes it is invalid.  We are given no knowledge that $B(c)$ and hence cannot assert $A(c) \land B(c)$, and hence cannot conclude $C(c)$

Comment: Indeed, exactly so.